# Wordpress AJAX Hide Load More Button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I've created a custom WP-Query with the possibility to load more posts on button click with AJAX. Everything works fine. Now I'd like to hide the button if there are less or exactly four posts. The button should also disappear if there are all posts loaded with AJAX.

I'd be very thankful if somebody could help me! Thank you in advance.

My PHP:

```
<div class="masonry category-single-magazin__inner entry-content">
    <?php $args = array('category_name' => 'magazin', 'posts_per_page' => '4', 'paged' => 1, 'orderby'=> 'date', 'order' => 'DESC'); $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args ); while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
    <article class="object <?php if ( get_field( 'beitragsfarbe' ) == 1 ) { echo 'object--blue'; } else { echo 'object--yellow'; } ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="lazy object__inner" data-src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                <div class="overline">
                    <h6>
                        <?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo $tag->name . ' '; }}?>
                    </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="object__inner__text content-no-margin">
                    <h4>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h4>
                    <p class="textlink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Mehr erfahren</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</div>

<button class="load-more reload-masonry button-full button-full--yellow">
    <div class="button-full__inner">Mehr anzeigen</div>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
        var page = 2;
        var pageNumber = <?php echo count_cat_post('magazin')/4; ?>;

        $('.load-more').on('click', function() {
            var data = {
                'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
                'page': page,
                'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>',
            };
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                $('.masonry').append(response);
                page++;
            });
        });

        if (page == (parseInt(pageNumber) - 1)) {
            $('.load-more').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

My functions.php:

```
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = array(
        'category_name' => 'magazin',
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby'=> 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post() ?>
<article class="object <?php if ( get_field( 'beitragsfarbe' ) == 1 ) { echo 'object--blue'; } else { echo 'object--yellow'; } ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="lazy-ajax object__inner" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>')">
                    <div class="overline"><h6><?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo $tag->name . ' '; }}?></h6></div>
                    <div class="object__inner__text content-no-margin">
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <p class="textlink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Mehr erfahren</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </article>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        <?php wp_die();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not write whole code but here is the possible solution. First you need to know how many pages of post are there, you can get total number of post by using following Wordpress function

```
<?php
     $count_posts = wp_count_posts(); 
     /*this function only works with post type is post .
         if you using for categories first you need to find how many 
        post are there in that categories.*/
 ?>
```

If you divide total count_post by number of post per page you will get total number of page.

Now you can simply check it in your javascript like this.

```
    var pageNumber = <?php echo (wp_count_posts()/4); ?>
//make sure pageNumber is number not string can use javascript parseInt function
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(page==(parseInt(pageNumber)-1)){
//send ajax request to get last page post but hide the button 
     }
});
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Solved the problem with counting category posts. But hiding the button is still not working... I've edited my script under the query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself. Although thank you for guiding me to the solution!
I've created a function for this with jQuery counting the visible posts:

```
function hideButton(){
    var poststotal = <?php echo count_cat_post('magazin'); ?>;
    var postsvisible = $('.masonry > article').length;
    if (poststotal == postsvisible) {
        $('.load-more').addClass('hidden');
    }
};
```